# How are UI events generated in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, routed-events, uievent

I am trying to understand how UI related RoutedEvents are generated in WPF.

For instance, how does pressing the left mouse button on a control starts the tunneling of `PreviewMouseDown`?

I couldn't find a clear answer myself. My intuition is that the messages received by the window (e.g. `WM_MOUSEFIRST`) are processed and events are raised as a consequence, but this is just my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually it *must* be `WM_MOUSEFIRST` and similar Windows events that trigger actions in WPF. No doubt. That is how *Windows* works.

Inside WPF, it uses [`EventManager`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/EventManager.cs) and [`GlobalEventManager`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/GlobalEventManager.cs) to handle events. A `Window` and all subsequent base classes registers itself at the `EventManager` (like [`Window`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,109) and [`FrameworkElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,2381) here).

The `EventManager` handles the actual events and takes care of the routing.

The actual mouse events are handled by [`HwndMouseInputProvider`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Interop/HwndMouseInputProvider.cs,54ed173aa104f51b) and some `Window` events by `Window` [itself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,4302).

Comment: Thank you, however peeking at the code `EventManager` and `GlobalEventManager` it seems to me these are not the classes that turn Window messages to WPF Events, am I wrong? Where does this happen?

Comment: The actual mouse events are handled by [`HwndMouseInputProvider`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Interop/HwndMouseInputProvider.cs,54ed173aa104f51b).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I was looking for! I'll wait a bit for other answers, then I'll mark yours as accepted.